# Does Ontology Consistency include Class Expression Satisfiability?

Tags: logic, computer-science

In the [OWL 2 DL's direct semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/) document, the following statements are made:

- Ontology Consistency: $O$ is consistent (or satisfiable) w.r.t. $D$ if a model of $O$ w.r.t. $D$ and $V$ exists.
- Class Expression Satisfiability: $CE$ is satisfiable w.r.t. $O$ and $D$ if a model $I = ( ΔI , ΔD , ⋅ ^C , ⋅ ^{OP} , ⋅ ^{DP} , ⋅ ^I , ⋅ ^{DT} , ⋅ ^{LT} , ⋅ ^{FA} , NAMED )$ of $O$ w.r.t. $D$ and $V$ exists such that $(CE)^C ≠ ∅$.

Does Ontology Consistency include Class Expression satisfiability? My guess would be no, since class expressions seem to be independent of the first statement, according to the information on the linked web page. But, shouldn't class expressions be fulfilled in a consistent ontology? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your intuition is correct: we may have a model of $O$, and thus it is satisfiable, where some class is empty, i.e. the corersponding class expression has no instances.

Comment: Ah, I see. thank you very much!